# How to remove the last \t (tab) in array map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I push my data inside an array and after that i use this code to have some join on that array.

```
var tsv = ArrExport.map(function(field) {
   return field.join("\t");
 }).join('\r\n');
```

The ouput of that is this

```
Data1 [Tab] Data2 [Tab] Data3 [Tab]
Data1 [Tab] Data2 [Tab] Data3 [Tab]
```

How can I remove the last `[tab]`?

Example

`Data1 [Tab] Data2 [Tab] Data3
 Data1 [Tab] Data2 [Tab] Data3`

Comment: Check for index of last item inside map function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.join` only adds delimiters between elements, not after them. If you're seeing an extra `[Tab]` at the end of the line, your array has an extra empty element at the end. Get a copy of the array without that last element by using [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and `join` the copy:

```
return field.slice(0, -1).join("\t");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check index for last array item

```
var tsv = ArrExport.map(function(field, index) {
   if (index != ArrExport.length - 1) {
      return field.join("\t");
   }
 }).join('\r\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I remove the last [tab]?

It seems that last item of your array is empty, just remove it first.

```
if ( ArrExport[ ArrExport.length - 1 ].length ) //check if last item is empty
{
    ArrExport.pop(); //if it is empty then remove that item
}
```

After this, just run your own code.